# Can I build Pipeline and create Release not from UI?

Tags: azure-devops, automation, azure-pipelines, cicd

I have projects with a lot of pipelines and releases that I need to run oftenly. There is an option to run those pipelines and releases from some shell and not from the UI?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of options You can use [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops) to get your pipeline to automatically trigger when certain conditions are met. Or you could use the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to manually trigger pipelines from outside the UI

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you often you want to run them you have a few options

If you want to run the pipelines every day (or every hour) then adding a [scheduled trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) is your best bet.

```
schedules:
  - cron: "0 6 * * 1"
    displayName: Weekly Monday 6AM build
    branches:
      include:
        - develop
```

If you want to run pipelines on a more ad hoc basis then you can run them from a command line using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)

Once this is installed you'll be able to run `az` commands. You can run `az` from a command line or powershell prompt

Install the Azure DevOps extension.

`az extension add --name azure-devops`

To log directly in to Azure devOps you'll need to generate a PAT with the appropriate permissions and then run

`az devops login --organization http://dev.azure.com/myorg` and you will be prompted for a PAT

You can also [set an environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) for the PAT and you can set a default organization and team project by using
`az devops configure --defaults organization=http://dev.azure.com/myorg project=myproject`

once you have this set up you can call `az pipelines` to do pipeline things. If you want to queue a pipeline then you can call

`az pipelines run --org http://dev.azure.com/myorg --project myproject --name az-cli`